# Try Catch inside function with return statement

Tags: java, spring, try-catch, slf4j

Hello I have a function that has a return statement. This is the function:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> findByNumber(String telefon) throws Exception {

JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSourceInregIvg);
List<Map<String, Object>> info1 = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select cif, den_client from b101_conturi where telefon=?", telefon);
 return info1;
```

}

I tried this adding try catch:

```
 public List<Map<String, Object>> findByNumber(String telefon) throws Exception {
       try {
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSourceInregIvg);
        List<Map<String, Object>> info1 = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select cif, den_client from b101_conturi where telefon=?", telefon);
       } catch(Exception e) {
       

       logger.error(e.printStackTrace());
       }
         return info1;
     
    }
```

But I get the error at `return info1` that it cannot find symbol and at `logger.error(e.printStackTrace());` I get the error void type not allowed here

How can I make a try catch inside a function with return statement. Thank you

Comment: When you reach the `return`, what should `info1`'s value be if the exception is thrown? Declare `info1` before the `try` and give it that value.

Comment: After the catch info 1 will be null, declare some value as the previous comment suggests

Comment: @jr593 it won't be null, it would be out of scope. That's the problem. If it was null it could be returned no problem, syntactically speaking.

Comment: 1) You should indent your code more carefully, the first error should be easier to recognize. 2) I *wonder* **¹** what is returned by `printStackTrace()` - can that be printed? || **¹** not really, the error message is already telling it

Answer (score 0):

In spring repository there is a handler for exception and no need to add a try catch block. @ExceptionHandler, @ControllerAdvice can be used to log the errors.